# Google Drive API, download and get content files from a account server

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api

So, i want to get all content in google drive. It only using one account, can we access it everytime in app without need to login it? How?

I also tried to read the documentation but still didn't find out

Comment: How do you have it set up? Do you have the credentials, and tokens stored? The tokens get refreshed for security reasons.

Comment: Yes, i have those

Comment: I want to get all pdfs inside my account and show it to user. That's my purpose to do that

Comment: If you have a G Suite domain, you can create a service account. If not you can share your pdf to the user account so he can see it without need for you to login.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of right now is save the refresh token of an account on server side and every time an user uses the app give them a new access token.

This way it should suit your needs, one account no login.

Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) for refresh token

Comment: Do you know how to get the access token? Google api in flutter isnt detail